# joining three tables together using Inner Joins

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Table aliases, list the first name, last name and start date of students enrolled on the java fundamentals module:

I am having some trouble when running the query below.

```
SELECT stu.StudFName, stu.StudLName, enrol.StartDate
From Student stu
INNER JOIN Enrolment enrol
ON stu.StudID = enrol.StudID
INNER JOIN Module mod
ON enrol.ModCode = mod.ModCode
WHERE mod.ModName = 'Java Fundamentals'
```

Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(StudID       INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY,
 StudFName    VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL,
 StudLName    VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL,
 DoB          DATE          NOT NULL,
 Sex          CHAR(1)       NOT NULL CHECK (Sex IN ('M', 'F')),
 Email        VARCHAR(30)   UNIQUE);


CREATE TABLE Staff
(StaffID      INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY,
 Title        VARCHAR(4)    CHECK (Title IN ('Prof', 'Dr', 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss')),
 StaffFName   VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL,
 StaffLName   VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL,
 Email        VARCHAR(30)   UNIQUE,
 Department   VARCHAR(25)   DEFAULT 'Not Assigned',
 Extension    INTEGER       CHECK (Extension BETWEEN 0001 AND 9999));


CREATE TABLE Module
(ModCode      CHAR(4)       PRIMARY KEY,
 ModName      VARCHAR(25)   NOT NULL,
 ModCredits   INTEGER       NOT NULL CHECK (ModCredits IN (15, 30, 45, 60)),
 ModLevel     CHAR(3)       NOT NULL CHECK (ModLevel   IN ('UG1', 'UG2', 'UG3', 'MSc')),
 ModLeader    INTEGER       NOT NULL,
 Foreign Key (ModLeader)    REFERENCES Staff (StaffID));


CREATE TABLE Enrolment
(ModCode      CHAR(4)       NOT NULL,
 StudID       INTEGER       NOT NULL,
 StartDate    DATE          NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (ModCode, StudID),
 Foreign Key (StudID)  REFERENCES Student (StudID),          
 Foreign Key (ModCode) REFERENCES Module (ModCode));
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It looks like you have misspelled student

Comment: show table structure

Comment: I would be very surprised if the module code were intended to be the same as the module name - otherwise there would be no need to join to the `Module` table at all. So I suspect that rather than this: `ON enrol.ModCode = mod.ModName` you mean this: `ON enrol.ModCode = mod.ModCode`.

Comment: Here is my code, when i run this it is returning table or view does not exist, the tables consist of StudID in the student table and StudFName and StudLName, in the enrolment table the fields ModCode, StudID and Start date occur, in the module table ModCode and ModName appear. Any suggestions? SQL> SELECT stu.StudFName, stu.StudLName, enrol.StartDate FROM Student stu INNER
 JOIN Enroment ON stu.StudID = enrol.StudID INNER JOIN Module mod ON enrol.ModCo
de = mod.ModCode WHERE mod.ModName = 'Java Fundamentals';

Comment: The question i am trying to come up with a solution for is as follows: Using Table aliases, list the first name, last name and start date of students enrolled on the java fundamentals module:

Comment: @GeorgeHalford, would it be possible for you to share the structure of your tables and the expected output?

Comment: @GeorgeHalford What is the trouble? The query looks fine. Do you get any error?

Comment: the table or view does not exist is the error i am getting

Answer (score 0):

The answer is... there is no trouble with your query.

It works just fine.
Check [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43cf6/1)

```
INSERT INTO Student (StudID, StudFName, StudLName, DoB, Sex, Email) VALUES
(1, 'Jack', 'Black', TO_DATE('2015/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'M', 'jack@email.com');
INSERT INTO Student (StudID, StudFName, StudLName, DoB, Sex, Email) VALUES
(2, 'Andrew', 'Wiggin', TO_DATE('2015/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'M', 'andrew@email.com');
INSERT INTO Student (StudID, StudFName, StudLName, DoB, Sex, Email) VALUES
(3, 'Bob', 'Marley', TO_DATE('2015/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'M', 'bob@email.com');

INSERT INTO Staff (StaffID, Title, StaffFName, StaffLName, Email, Extension) VALUES
(1, 'Prof', 'Joe', 'Smith', 'stuff@emal.com', 0001);

INSERT INTO Module (ModCode, ModName, ModCredits, ModLevel, ModLeader) VALUES
(1, 'Java Fundamentals', 30, 'UG1', 1);
INSERT INTO Module (ModCode, ModName, ModCredits, ModLevel, ModLeader) VALUES
(2, 'C# Fundamentals', 15, 'UG2', 1);

INSERT INTO Enrolment (ModCode, StudID, StartDate) VALUES
(1, 1, TO_DATE('2015/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd'));
INSERT INTO Enrolment (ModCode, StudID, StartDate) VALUES
(1, 2, TO_DATE('2015/01/02', 'yyyy/mm/dd'));
INSERT INTO Enrolment (ModCode, StudID, StartDate) VALUES
(2, 3, TO_DATE('2015/01/03', 'yyyy/mm/dd'));

-------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT stu.StudFName, stu.StudLName, enrol.StartDate
From Student stu
INNER JOIN Enrolment enrol ON stu.StudID = enrol.StudID
INNER JOIN Module mod ON enrol.ModCode = mod.ModCode
WHERE mod.ModName = 'Java Fundamentals'
```

Result

```
STUDFNAME   STUDLNAME   STARTDATE
----------------------------------------
Jack        Black       January, 01 2015
Andrew      Wiggin      January, 02 2015
```